# Codeontime with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am searching for a fast code generator tool. I am using my own objects which ones genereted as POCO from Entity Framework. Is it possible to use my custom DAL with wcf on codeontime?

Comment: You might want to flesh this question out a little bit with more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know it was asked very long time a go. did you happened to find a solution for that? I want to speak with the system from out side.    
   Thanks

Comment: I am not using codeontime. Using my own framework for web services.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to re-generate the thing using CodeOnTime's own framework.

Do contact the vendor CodeOnTime for using their own framework instead.